# jQuery animate css border-radius property (webkit, mozilla)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, border, css

Is there a way in **jQuery** to animate the css3 **border-radius** property available in Webkit and Mozilla browsers?

I haven't found a plugin that will do it.

```
-webkit-border-radius

-moz-border-radius
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I originally expected that something like...

```
$("selector")
  .css({borderRadius: 10});
  .animate({borderRadius: 30}, 900);
```

...would work. But, I was wrong: Webkit allows you to *set* the value for all four corners via `borderRadius`, but won't let you read it back - so with the code above, the animation will always start at 0 instead of 10. IE has the same problem. Firefox *will* let you read it back, so everything works as expected there.

Well... border-radius has sort of a history of implementation differences.

Fortunately, there's a work-around: just specify each corner radius individually:

```
$("selector")
  .css({
    borderTopLeftRadius: 10, 
    borderTopRightRadius: 10, 
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 10, 
    borderBottomRightRadius: 10 })
  .animate({
    borderTopLeftRadius: 30, 
    borderTopRightRadius: 30, 
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 30, 
    borderBottomRightRadius: 30}, 900);
```

Note that if you wish to maintain compatibility with older browsers, you can go all-out and use the old browser-prefixed names:

```
$("selector")
  .css({
    borderTopLeftRadius: 10, 
    borderTopRightRadius: 10, 
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 10, 
    borderBottomRightRadius: 10,
    WebkitBorderTopLeftRadius: 10, 
    WebkitBorderTopRightRadius: 10, 
    WebkitBorderBottomLeftRadius: 10, 
    WebkitBorderBottomRightRadius: 10, 
    MozBorderRadius: 10 
  })
  .animate({
    borderTopLeftRadius: 30, 
    borderTopRightRadius: 30, 
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 30, 
    borderBottomRightRadius: 30,
    WebkitBorderTopLeftRadius: 30, 
    WebkitBorderTopRightRadius: 30, 
    WebkitBorderBottomLeftRadius: 30, 
    WebkitBorderBottomRightRadius: 30, 
    MozBorderRadius: 30 
  }, 900);
```

This starts to get pretty crazy though; I would avoid it if possible.

Comment: Well, sort of. So far, if there's any radius set in the style sheet, the corners will snap square, then animate to 30 (to use your example) from there. It seems to want to go from 0 to whatever value is given. I get the same result in Safari and Firefox 3.5 beta.

Comment: Correction: It seems to work correctly in Firefox. Safari only wants to increment.

Comment: Looks like whatever direction I go, Safari always starts by snapping to 0. Any workaround ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @patrick: yes, i've found a work-around. Can't test in Safari, but works in Chrome (which exhibited the same bug, so i'd assume it's a general Webkit thing). I've updated the answer, give it a try...

Comment: this code did not work for me, firefox 5, jquery 1.5 , i changed the case like so - BorderRadius to borderRadius , throughout and it worked

Comment: Thanks, @Blowsie - I should have guessed it'd be lower-case once the dust settled. I've updated the answer to indicate the state of this technique on current browsers.

Comment: Has this changed now in 2013 ?

Comment: Is it in percentage or pixel? I would like to use percentage.

Answer (score 3):

Use cssHooks.

This will help you out:

http://www.webmuse.co.uk/articles/border_radius_csshook_with_internet_explorer_support/

Links to the cssHooks:

https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Juste an advice, we can use a function to detect browser's CSS prefix
Here a sample code.. http://jsfiddle.net/molokoloco/f6Z3D/