# Webkit Border Radius Animation Clipping

Tags: jquery, webkit, border, mask, css

I'm animating open a lightbox (nothing special or crazy) and am having border-radius problems in Chrome, Opera and Safari. All other browsers (including mobile ones I've tested) work just fine. Basically, after clicking a DIV the lightbox animates from one border-radius to another while opening. Content inside of the DIV spills out during the animation (clipping). Other browsers don't have an issue with this, and from the research I've done it's Webkit not respecting overflow:hidden.

**Here is the JS to open the lightbox (inside click event):**

```
$('#SC_Lightbox').css({
borderTopLeftRadius:'100px',
borderTopRightRadius:'100px',
borderBottomLeftRadius:'100px',
borderBottomRightRadius:'100px',
WebkitBorderTopLeftRadius:'100px',
WebkitBorderTopRightRadius:'100px',
WebkitBorderBottomLeftRadius:'100px',
WebkitBorderBottomRightRadius:'100px',
MozBorderRadius:'10px',
borderRadius:'10px'})
.animate({
'opacity':1,'width':'300px','height':'500px','top':'120px','left':'200px',
borderTopLeftRadius:'10px',
borderTopRightRadius:'10px',
borderBottomLeftRadius:'10px',
borderBottomRightRadius:'10px',
WebkitBorderTopLeftRadius:'10px',
WebkitBorderTopRightRadius:'10px',
WebkitBorderBottomLeftRadius:'10px',
WebkitBorderBottomRightRadius:'10px',
MozBorderRadius:'10px',
borderRadius:'10px'
},{duration:500,queue:false});
```

**Here is the CSS of the Lightbox (everything applied after load):**

```
#SC_Lightbox {
    background-color: #333333;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
    display: block;
    height: 350px;
    left: 500px;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999999;
    line-height: 1;}
```

The other weird thing is that the problematic browsers also seem to have an issue animating/rendering the WebkitBorderBottomRightRadius???

I've also tried another forum suggestion and added:

```
-webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
```

to force overflow:hidden in Webkit, but unfortunately there's a box-shadow which is removed by doing this and it's also a pretty choppy solution.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't it `border-radius` and `-moz-border-radius` and `-webkit-border-radius` and all of the others? Whats with the camel case?

Comment: I thought that when scripting the border-radius property that's the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Also, why are you doing all of the corner-specific definitions? If every corner is the same, you should just need one definition for each vendor prefix. I'm not saying that will fix your problem, but it surely won't hurt. Animations are expensive; try to make it easy on the browser.

Comment: Do a quick google search for border-radius and see if you see any camel case definitions like that. I sure didn't. Another tip -- instead of making that jquery `css` call before the animation, create a css class with all of that stuff and just do `$('#SC_Lightbox').addClass('bigRadius').animate({...`

Comment: All of the border radii are variables, I just simplified it for the question. Regarding the scripting border-radius and css definition before animation it was pulled from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010058/jquery-animate-css-border-radius-property-webkit-mozilla?rq=1

Comment: wow! thanks for sharing. That is pretty crazy. I'd consider putting that link in your question and also adding a jsfiddle so people can mess around with it themselves.