# Animate border-radius by multiplying its current value

Tags: jquery

It must be possible to animate the `border-radius` of a set of objects but I am having a hell of a time figuring it out. Specifically I am trying to double the size of circular divs, each one has a different diameter. I have tried the suggestions of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010058/jquery-animate-css-border-radius-property-webkit-mozilla) to no avail (the difference being I want to multiply the current value). Take your best stab at my [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dfjosh/RgJsU/7/). Or look at my code below. The `width` and `height` work fine, but the `border-radius` does not.

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('.box').each(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        element.animate({
            'width' : element.width()*2,
            'height' : element.height()*2,
            'border-top-left-radius' : element.css('border-top-left-radius')*2,
            'border-top-right-radius' : element.css('border-top-right-radius')*2,
            'border-bottom-left-radius' : element.css('border-bottom-left-radius')*2,
            'border-bottom-right-radius' : element.css('border-bottom-right-radius')*2,
        }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `border-radius: 50%;` in `css`

For egs:

```
#one {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;/* Use 50% here to make circle */
    background: cornflowerblue;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

**Similarly** for **#two** and **#three**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RgJsU/12/)

Comment: Thank you so much Rohan. This allows me to animate the width and height and not even worry about the border radius. Perfect answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...
Animate  border-radius with the width and height.

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('.box').each(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        element.animate({
            'width' : element.width()*2,
            borderRadius : element.width(),
            'height' : element.height()*2
        }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

Updated jsfiddle link here. : http://jsfiddle.net/RgJsU/14/

Comment: This is a worthy idea though I think Rohan's approach is better. Your link to your jsfiddle is broken too. Thank you so much for the answer though. It seems like it would work since it would be half the value of the width.

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't notice that.
Now I have updated the fiddle link. And thanks for the comment.