# jQuery .animate() only animates in Chrome, instantaneous change in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I have looked at other posts and there is a running solution involving "event" however I can't see how that fits into my code. As it stands the .animate() function, more specifically the duration functionality, doesn't seem to work unless I use chrome.

Here is my code.

**index.html**

```
<title>Quests Development Space</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
```

```
<div id="circle"></div>
```

**javascript.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#circle").click(function() {

        $(this).animate({
            borderRadius:"0px"
        }, {
            duration: 1600
        });

    });

});
```

I have tried iterations without the ",{duration: x}" and just ", 1500" as I have seen it used both ways however neither works in anything except Chrome.
The function turns a circle into a square and still does in all browsers however it is only animated in Chrome.

**Edit:**

**stylesheet.css**

```
#circle {

    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: blue;

}
```

Here is the CSS for those who asked though as I said it does work just only animates on Chrome.

**Edit 2:**

Breaking News!

It seems it is animating however it is "blinking" to border-radius 0 then animating inwards.

Comment: what are the associated styles

Comment: Have you tried just `borderRadius: 0`?

Comment: @MattParlane No I have tried stuff in between no luck.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Added them to the post as an edit, can't believe I forgot to post initially mb.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010058/jquery-animate-css-border-radius-property-webkit-mozilla

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kgaLaeLu/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny That is cool, however this question had relevance, as to a newbie like me it was unclear that -webkit- and -moz- tags were needed in the first place as the code still worked (just not as intended) otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code snippet:

```
$(function() {
  $("#circle").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
      borderTopRightRadius: 0,
      borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
      borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
      WebkitBorderTopLeftRadius: 0,
      WebkitBorderTopRightRadius: 0,
      WebkitBorderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
      WebkitBorderBottomRightRadius: 0,
      MozBorderRadius: 0
    }, 1600);
  });
});
```

You need to set all cross browser border radius properties to run it across all the browsers.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/o4E0SOpQrWBKL)

Comment: Wow okay that works, do you mind explaining why? I know what the code is doing/stating however why would this function properly(animating outwards) over my original code (that blinked to borderRadius0 then animated inwards)?

Comment: I'm surprised there's the need for the Webkit prefixes, as Chrome works, you only need the first four (borderTopLeftRadius to borderBottomRightRadius) for this to work in all modern browsers - which is why copying 4 year old SO answers isn't always the best answer

Comment: I wasn't intended to earn points by giving answer rather than just helping out developers. I have already voted to close.